# How to fix "error";invalid json in fetch api

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, fetch

I am using fetch api to post data to my API hosted on heroku. I am getting error message {error:Invalid JSON}

What do I do.

```
const signUpBtn2 = document.getElementById("enter2");
signUpBtn2.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData()
    const fetchData = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: formData
    };



    fetch("https://polityco.herokuapp.com/auth/signup", fetchData)
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function(text) {
        console.log([text]);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
});
```

I expect json response but the response I get is [{…}]
0: {error: "Invalid JSON"}
length: 1

Comment: Make sure it actually returns JSON?

Comment: You should probably check `res.ok` to make sure the request was successful since fetch does not reject HTTP error status codes, but rather just sets `ok` to false

Comment: it should be "Content-Type"

Comment: What is the response you are getting from the server? Seems like it is not valid JSON, or possibly an HTTP error code.

Comment: Looks to me like your page on heroku is expecting JSON, but FormData's output is not JSON. This might help: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/09/convert-formdata-json-object/

Comment: I have done all but still getting {error: "Invalid JSON"} in the console.

Comment: Your `formData` is empty, so if you're not handling that scenario..

Comment: Is ```formData``` defined? If it is, is it valid JSON? And if it is, is the response JSON?